# Codename One Facebook/Android

Tags: codenameone

Android build fails when I include the build hint "facebook.appId". iOS build works fine. Excerpt from the Android build log (I hope this is the relevant bit):

> Merged dex A (41 defs/6.4KiB) with dex B (43 defs/53.5KiB). Result is
>   84 defs/71.7KiB. Took 0.2s Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Lbolts/AggregateException;
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lbolts/AggregateException;
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
>         at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>        :transformClassesWithDexForRelease FAILED :transformClassesWithDexForRelease (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main])
>   completed. Took 2 mins 55.612 secs.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Any suggestions, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

There is a conflict with the bolt jar facebook is including it and parse4cn1 is also including it.
Try to remove it by building the parse4cn1 without the bolts-android-1.2.1.jar file that is under the parse4cn1/native/android/ directory

Comment: I deleted all occurences of bolts-android-1.2.1.jar, and came one step further. Now I get this error message:  _[dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
       [dx]  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)_ However, a small test project builds just fine.

Comment: add the "android.multidex=true" build hint to overcome this

Comment: Sorry, tried again, same error. I added the build hint "android.multidex", with value = "true".

Answer (score 0):

Do you have leadbolts enabled in your project?

It looks like a conflict between leadbolts and facebook. Also try building with `android.gradle=false` and see if that works around the issue.

Comment: I tried to build with android.gradle=false, with the same result. There seems to be a conflict with parse4cn1. As soon as I add parse4cn1.cn1lib to a project with facebook.appId set to something, the Android build fails.